simulation with transition probability
I would like to simulate a CIR process defined by a probability transition enter image description here . However, I'm stuck. For example, how should I conduct the first simulation? I have experience with simulation using the Euler scheme and other methods directly from the SDE, but I'm unsure how to proceed given a transition probability. All I have in mind is that if we simulate a uniform random variable, the inverse of the CDF applied to U will have the same law as my process. Is the same logic applicable to transition probabilities?
enter image description here

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

The answer is to use the GWK method by insert answer here.
